# Data fetching performance improve from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

> For example, i have a table "tbl_book" with 100 records or more with multiple column like book_name, book_publisher,book_author,book_rate in mysql "db_bookshop". Now i would like to fetch them all by one query without iterate 100 times instead of one or two time looping. Is it possible? Is there any tricky way to do that. Generally we do what

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT desire_column_name FROM table_name WHERE clause");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $row['book_name']; 
    $row['book_publisher']; 
    $row['book_author']; 
    ..........
    $row['book_rate']; 
}

// Or we may can use mysqli_query(); -mysqli_fetch_row(), mysqli_fetch_array(), mysqli_fetch_assoc();
```

> My question is, is there any idea or any tricky way that we can be
>   avoided 1oo times iterate for fetching 1oo records? It's may be wired
>   to someone but one of the most experience programmer told me that it's
>   possible. But unfortunately i was not able to learn it from him. I
>   feel sorry for him because he is not anymore. Advance thanks for your idea sharing.

Comment: You are looking for a way to avoid the `while` loop, right?

Comment: This question makes no sense and makes assumptions that aren't true. Why use `mysql_` functions? That's been deprecated since eons ago. Had you used `PDO`, this code translates to `$records = $pdo->query(".....")->fetchAll();`. You are fetching everything with 1 query, why do you think you're querying anything 100 times? Did you read the manual at all?

Comment: There is no doubt that you are an most experience programmer. With all my honor and respect i would like to say to you, you did not read my question with full concentration. You did not think it with taking time you just see and express you comment.

Comment: Although it is quite possible that one person can take your question wrong, but if it happens with *every* response, then it's probably something wrong with your question, not answers.

Comment: Do switch to mysqli_ interface !

Comment: Please clarify the question to explain what worries you about the "100".  There are at least 2 different interpretations running through the answers so far.

Comment: This question should be closed until it and the attitude of its originator is improved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer - **NO**, it's impossible to fetch more than one record from a database without a loop.

But the the question here is that you don't want it.

There is no point in "just fetching" the data - you're always going to do something with it. *With each row.* Obviously, a loop is a natural way to do something with each row. Therefore, there is no point in trying to avoid a loop.
Which renders your question rather meaningless.

Regarding performance. The truth is that you experience **not a single performance problem** related to fetching just 100 records from a database.  Which renters your problem an imaginary one.

The only plausible question I can think off your post is your performance as a programmer, as lack of education makes you write a lot of unnecessary code. If you manage to ask a certain question regarding that matter, you'll be shown a way to avoid the useless repetitive typing.

Comment: Sir, I am not such an experience person like you all. Experience programmer might have able to do their desire thing by looping one where UN-experience cannot. UN-experience programmer do the same thing in a wrong way.I sad at my question one of the most experience programmer told me that which I do getting 100 or more records, he can do it just by one or two looping.

Comment: It's not about mysql syntax or pdo or msqli functions. It's about coding thought. I am a learner. My goal is to be well known innovative programmer, therefore i always follow how do you thought, how you do writing code. I love programming. I love to follow as a roll model like you people who are most experience. Who has been worked for a long time in that sector. With love and respect. @  Your Common Sense

Comment: We do not know what was your conversation with other programmer, so we cannot judge. If you need only ONE record out of 100, then indeed you can fetch only one. And you can ask how to do that. But if you need all 100, I can assure you that it's impossible to get them all without a loop. If the other guy says otherwise, he just have no idea what he is talking about

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Some APIs do fetch all the rows _into the client_, then the client code must _loop_ to get them.  This is quite different than having a round trip to the server for each row.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `mysql_query` the mysql extension is deprecated:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0.

-- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

When you use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) you can fetch all items without looping over query like this

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'dbuser', 'dbpass');
$statement = $connection->query('SELECT ...');

$rows = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: His expressed concern is about performance, while of course fetchAll() don't get you the data in a puff of a smoke right out of nowhere, but utilizing exactly the same loop internally.

Comment: I should appreciate your act. You have understood what i was thinking. What about i concern. Thanks.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You are correct. I am not in the mood to squabble about technical details that don't matter to the person asking. I recognized that this is likely what they were looking for and provided the answer. They do not have to loop in the sense that it's not necessary to `foreach`, it is done internally by PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `mysql_fetch_assoc`?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT desire_column_name FROM table_name WHERE clause");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    // do stuff here like..

    if (!empty($row['some_field'])){
        echo $row["some_field"];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to read all 100 records without loop by hardcoding the main column values, but that would involve 100 x number of columns to be listed, and there could be limitation on the number of columns you can display in MySQL.

eg,

```
select 
case when book_name='abc' then book_name end Name, 
case when book_name='abc' then book_publisher end as Publisher, 
case when book_name='abc' then book_author end as Author, 
case when book_name='xyz' then book_name end Name, 
case when book_name='xyz' then book_publisher end as Publisher, 
case when book_name='xyz' then book_author end as Author,
...
...
from 
db_bookshop;
```

It's not practical but if you have less rows to query you might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The time taken to ask the MySQL server for something is far greater than one iteration through a client-side `WHILE` loop.  So, to improve performance, the goal is to have the `SELECT` go to the server in *one* round trip.  Different API calls do this or don't do this; read their details.

I have written a lot of UIs with MySQL under the covers.  I think nothing of fetching a few dozen rows at once, and then build a `<table>` (or something) with the results.  I rarely fetch more than 100, not because of performance, but because 100 is (usually) too much for the user to take in on a single web page.

Also, I think nothing of issuing several, maybe dozens, of queries in support of a single web page.  The delay is insignificant, especially when compared to the user's time for reading, digesting, and moving to the next page.  So, I try to give the user a digestible amount of info without having to click to another page to get more.  There are tradeoffs.

When it is practical to have SQL do the 'digesting', do so.  It is faster for MySQL do do a `SUM()` and return just the total, rather than return dozens of rows for the client to add up.  This is mostly a 'bandwidth' issue.  Either way, MySQL will fetch (internally) all the needed rows.